# underfilled whipper canisters

Tags: equipment, whipper

I see a lot of info on overfilled whippers but what about underfilled. Let's say I have a 1/2 liter whipper which is 500cc. I know I can get away with just putting in 250cc of liquid but what if I put in 125cc of liquid and then charge it. Will it hurt the whipper? Will the liquid be overcharged (too much n2o for the liquid) or undercharged (decreased pressure because N2o is spread over a larger non-liquid volume)? If undercharged, would I just have to add a second charge? Thanks. Whipping expands to several times the original volume and for some things, several cups is leading to a lot of waste.

Answer (score 1):

I do it all the time it should work fine with a single charger. But keep in mind that, you always have an (almost) fix amount of waste of cream (or other product); the lower your starting volume is, the higher will be the ratio of wasting the product.